# angularjs share data between controllers (service approach) - watcher is no called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm struggling with sharing data between controllers with the service approach in angularjs. From somewhere here on stackoverflow I got this working code (sorry, I miss the original source) and I extendet it.

[jsbin sourcecode](http://jsbin.com/vitihexeyo/edit?html,js,output)

(updatet version: http://jsbin.com/hadegec/5/edit?html,js,output)

All is working fine with the original source, adding items to cart and the total price is updated in the CartCtrl.

I tried to extend it with a very simple message. But while the items watcher works very fine, the watcher to my new messageCart is not working. I really cannot see the difference between the items update and my new message test. It must be the watcher, because if I set the `$scope.messageCart` inside the `item-watcher (console.log("w-Items:"+Order.getmessage());` I allways get the correct string...

Any idea?

Comment: You never change the value of `messageT`, so what exactly is the purpose of `$scope.$watch('messageT'`?

Comment: Oh no.... also struggling with testcode on jsbin. http://jsbin.com/hadegec/5/edit?html,js,output

nearly the same... the messageT (or in the updatet version the messageCart) is set in the this.addToOrder = function(item) { method! Every time i add an item to the cart, the message should show the current time.

Comment: You don't change `messageCart` in `addToOrder`. You only set it once: `$scope.messageCart = Order.getmessage();`. Afterwards it doesn't change. There is no magical connection between `Order.messageOrder` and `$cope.messageCart`.

Comment: I don't understand not yet. No I don't set the '$scope.messageCart' thats right, but the idea is the same as it is with 'items'. I set the '$scope.messageCart' to the 'Order.getmessage' as it is made with the working '$scope.items = Order.items'. The ''$scope.messageCart' is not set. Thats true. But the 'Order.messageOrder' is set in 'addToOrder'. And the first call shows "testrun", that means that 'messageCart' is properly set to 'Order.getmessage()' The console.log shows it correct - everytime 'items-watcher' is triggered, a new output occurs.

Comment: _"but the idea is the same as it is with 'items'"_ - No, it's not. `$scope.items` is an array, and you use `$watchCollection` for it. Moreover the contents of the array changes, when you add an item, but `$scope.messageCart` does not change. Never.

Comment: [??] can you PLEASE update my not working example to make it run as expected? Many thanks... it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

- not watch on (unchagend) message string property of scope

`$scope.ordernewmessage = Order.getOrderMessage();
$scope.$watch('ordernewmessage ', function() {`

- but watch a function return the service property

**`$scope.$watch(function(){return Order.message;}, function(){`**

The last thing I don't understand is the difference betweeen the array property 'items' and the string propery 'message'. I don't understand, why the '$scope.itemsCart' reference to 'Order.items' is detected as changed while the '$scope.ordernewmessage'  set like this; '$scope.ordernewmessage = Order.getOrderMessage()' is not changed...

Comment: _"I don't understand, why the '$scope.itemsCart' reference to 'Order.items' is detected as changed while the '$scope.ordernewmessage' set like this"_ Ironically this sentence explains why. One is a reference, the other not. If I give you a book and a new edition gets published, then the book I gave you doesn't change. If you want the new edition you need a new book. But if I give you a link to a webpage, then you will always see the newest version when you visit the page. `$scope.ordernewmessage` is a String, a primitive immutable value. `$scope.itemsCart` is a reference, not unlike a link.